# When is "controlling for" effects nonsensical?

Tags: interpretation, biostatistics, controlling-for-a-variable

I am not as knowledgeable about statistics as I would like and I am looking for resources to help me understand what kinds of questions are meaningful and which are nonsensical. We are developing some data analysis and transformation techniques in our lab for controlling what genomics people call "[batch effects](https://www.10xgenomics.com/resources/analysis-guides/introduction-batch-effect-correction)" between different data sets, understood loosely as trying to integrate these into a single data set so elements of the two sets can be directly compared.

Source: https://sysbiowiki.soe.ucsc.edu/node/323

> Batch effect correction is the procedure of removing variability from
> your data that is not due to your variable of interest (e.g. cancer
> type).

The techniques are ad hoc and heuristic but in spite of lacking formal justification we are proceeding under the hope that they are still of practical utility. The idea is to "regress out" or "control for" the systematic differences between the two data sets, leaving only the individual variation within the data sets, so that the whole data set can be analyzed all at once and directly compare elements of the two data sets.

Examples:

- We have data on neuron morphology from animals across different species and different parts of the brain, and we have developed a pairwise similarity score between neurons. We would like to construct a new data set which controls for morphological variation due to location in the brain, so that we can isolate the effect of species differences on morphology and identify a phylogenetic tree in this data.
- We have a data set on neuron morphology where the axon was present in the analysis and a data set collected using a different technology where the axon was removed and we only have the soma and dendrites. We would like to perform "batch correction" to integrate these two data sets and control for the missing axon data in one, trying to regress out the difference in morphology due to the missing axon, by modifying the similarity metric so that two cells are considered identical if one perfectly matches a fragment of another.
- We are trying to study the spatial distribution of proteins within cells but the cells sometimes have such different shapes that it is hard to meaningfully compare the distribution of proteins within cells. For example if the cell is undergoing mitosis then the overall cell shapes will be very dissimilar. We want to perhaps devise a geometric transformation which distorts all the cell shapes into, say, a perfect circle, and then we can compare the protein distributions within the cell without worrying about differences due to cell shape.

I have concerns about these and other examples. I am not able to confidently state what exactly is the problem which is why I am asking here, but part of the problem is what seems to be implicit wishful thinking about our ability to meaningfully resolve conterfactual questions, which is a problem mentioned in this paper on [misunderstanding of analysis of covariance](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11261398/). (However this paper addresses ANCOVA specifically and I am not sure how general the critique is meant to be.) For example

- Would these neurons still be morphologically dissimilar if they were taken from animals of the same species?
- How morphologically similar would these neurons be if we had the additional axon data that is missing for one?
- How similar would these protein distributions be from cells of different shapes if the underlying cells were the same shape?

In each case you could argue that the question is nonsense, independently and a priori of the mathematical methods being developed here. Species contributes a core part of morphology, you can't talk about what a given neuron's morphology would look like if it came from another animal, how can we compare two neurons from different species and "control" for that difference? How can you compare a cell with missing morphological data to a cell with all morphological data and say that the cells would be similar or dissimilar if we had the additional data? The shape of the cell is an integral part of the shape of the protein distribution, how can you say "these cells have similar protein distributions if you control for their different shapes?"

My specific questions are:

1. Are the critiques I have raised justified, or am I misunderstanding the point of batch correction/statistical control?
2. Are the problems I am pointing out actually *fatal* in the sense that the results to the questions will be literally nonsensical/uninterpretable, or is this kind of batch correction analysis/control/regression worth doing, at least for the sake of exploratory data analysis and forming hypotheses for further testing? My lab is very pragmatic and being a stickler and saying "this hypothesis of normal residuals/a zero skew distribution is unsatisfied, so we can't do the test" will not go over well if I cannot convincingly demonstrate or explain that the results will be genuinely nonsensical. "Well, we have no other choice, we have to be practical to get scientific results, the only alternative is to just not regress out by the covariate at all."
3. Where can I read more about the philosophy of "batch correction", "controlling for differences", "regressing out on this" so that I can develop a better understanding of my questions raised in 1.) and 2.)?

Comment: Is your question [in two parts]: 1) what does it mean to "control" for [a variable] and 2) under what conditions can we say we control for factors so that disparate data can be combined and analyzed reliably?

Comment: Yes. In addition to 1 I would say I have an intuitive understanding of what it means but I don't have confidence that my understanding is coherent/grounded.

Comment: Matt Yglesias and Ezra Klein discussed the "festival of controls" from a political view at https://www.vox.com/2014/4/9/5597392/fancy-math-cant-erase-the-gender-pay-gap and https://www.vox.com/2014/12/1/7311417/race-law-controls, e.g.: "Take hours worked, which is a standard control in some wage gap studies. Women tend to work fewer hours than men. If you control for hours worked, then some of the gender wage gap vanishes" but "women work shorter hours because we hold women to a higher standard of housekeeping, and because they tend to be assigned the bulk of childcare responsibilities."

Comment: As far as combining data, you can think of "controlling" for a covariate or cofactor a bit like a handicap in golf. By adjusting for the baseline skill level of the player, you can inspect the stroke counts of a heterogeneous group of players and definitively say if a particular course is harder, or easier, than others.

Answer (score 3):

"Controlling for" effects is nonsensical when what you are trying to "control for" can't be disentangled from the phenomenon of primary interest.

Sometimes that isn't much of a problem at all. Say that you are using two electronic weighing devices. One is completely functional; the display on the other is broken, but you have access to an internal electronic signal that is proportional to an object's weight. If you could weigh some of the same objects on both devices, you could calibrate the signal from the device with the broken display and then use data from both devices in your subsequent analysis. You can think of that as "controlling for" the difference between the two devices.

That's the basic idea underlying "batch effect" correction in genomics. In any experiment, most of the 20,000+ RNA products of genes won't be affected by experimental manipulation. Even though you might not have any single sample evaluated in all "batches" (different RNA sequencing runs in this case), you can correct for systematic differences among "batches" insofar as the assumption that most gene products aren't affected holds.

At the other extreme, say that you wanted to test whether two treatments led to different clinical outcomes in an observational study. When you examine the data, however, you find that only individuals with mild disease received Treatment A while only individuals with severe disease received Treatment B. There's no way reliably to disentangle the underlying disease severity from the effects of the treatments.

For the wide range of situations between those extremes, a good reference is "[Causal Inference: What If](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/)" by Hernán and Robins. It starts with a solid explanation of "*Causal inference without models*" that helps to distinguish the fundamental conceptual issues from the additional complexity introduced by parametric modeling. In rough outline, if there is enough overlap in what you are trying to "control for" among the groups/treatments/classifications of primary interest, you *might* be able (with care) to evaluate what would have been observed if all individuals had the same values of the covariates you are trying to "control for."

The problems raised in [your cited paper on ANCOVA](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11261398/)* have mostly to do with misinterpretation of ANCOVA results. ANCOVA is just one particular form of a linear regression model, with a categorical predictor (e.g., treatment type) of primary interest and a continuous variable (covariate) also related to outcome. As that paper notes in the second column of page 46, thinking of the covariate "as another substantive variable" is a "sound, relatively familiar" strategy.

Problems arise when you think that this necessarily "controls for" the association of the covariate with outcome in a way that correctly identifies the effects of the categorical predictor of primary interest. Unless you have the correct model for the association of the covariate and its interactions with the categorical predictor with outcome and there are no unobserved variables also associated with outcome, that interpretation can be incorrect. "The less widely known concept of *propensity score*" noted in your cited paper as a strategy has become much better appreciated in the 20+ years since your cited paper appeared; see Hernán and Robins or the 600+ pages tagged with [`propensity-scores`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/propensity-scores) on this site.

You need to use your understanding of the subject matter to apply those principles to the examples you cite. As you proceed, don't forget that "[All models are wrong, but some are useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong)."

---

*GA Miller and JP Chapman, "Misunderstanding analysis of covariance," J Abnorm Psychol 110:40-8 (2001).  doi: 10.1037//0021-843x.110.1.40.